# Stacking models with Orange Data Mining

Tags: data-science, orange

I am using Orange Data Mining for some classification tasks. I don't understand why I can't use a stacked model to make predictions using a test dataset. I have read most of the documentation and I couldn't find anything on this issue.
I am using Orange 3.21.0.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTB10.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need a model to use it for predictions. And every model needs a data to be trained on. Connect the first File widget to Stacking and it should work.